# How can I use this font in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts

[image]

I encounter the font used for `add-edge` many times among documents generated from LaTeX, e.g. `beamer` presentations. But I have no idea how can I use this font in my own document written from scratch. How can I include this font into my document?

FYI the source of the algorithm is [here](https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/schachte/papers/sas16.pdf).

Comment: Havee you tried `\textsf{add-edge}`? The document uses CM and that looks a lot like CM's sans serif version.